# Showing Image in Python Code & Basic Multiplying

Tags: python

I'm having problems showing a certain image when using the IF clause. The idea is to show a picture of the "1" side of a dice when the random number generated equals "1" and so forth for each number.

I am also having trouble making the winning outcome double the bet. For instance, betting $10 and winning $20. I keep getting $1010

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = str(form.getvalue("name"))
bet = str(form.getvalue("bet"))


print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Lab 10</title>
</head><body>
"""
import random
die1 = str(random.randint(1,6))
die2 = str(random.randint(1,6))

print "<p>Thanks for playing, "+name+" . You rolled "+die1+".</p>"
print "<p> Your opponent rolled "+die2+".</p>"

if die1==die2:
print "You win $"+bet+"!</p>"
if die1>die2:
print "You win $"+bet*2+"!</p>"
if die1<die2:
print "You lose $"+bet+"! Try again.</p>"

if die1==int("1"):
print "<img src='dice-1.png' alt='1' width='107' height='107' />"



print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Comment: As far as "$1010", note how you change the die roll into a string before multiplying it by two. Just a few lines later, you compare this string to an integer that you get from a string representation of that integer. Why use `int("1")` instead of `1`? You have some study time ahead of you regarding types.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 after "Thanks for playing, you rolled..."

Comment: Okay, so what's the question? Are you getting exceptions? Bad results? Asking us to write code for you?

Comment: @skrrgwasme Why isnt my image showing? and Why isnt my "bet" doubling when the user "wins"?

Comment: @aaandrewp Okay - you should edit your question, and clearly state those objectives. Clearly describe what you expected to happen and what actually did happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing strings and integers into each other and making comparisons that won't raise an error in Python 2, but won't work either. Be consistent in whether something is a string or a number. Use `str.format` to interpolate values into your strings without having to worry about concatenation.

```
name = str(form.getvalue("name"))
bet = int(form.getvalue("bet"))

print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Lab 10</title>
</head><body>
"""
import random
die1 = random.randint(1,6)
die2 = random.randint(1,6)

print "<p>Thanks for playing, {}. You rolled {}.</p>".format(name, die1)
print "<p> Your opponent rolled {}.</p>".format(die2)

if die1 == die2:
    print "You win ${}!</p>".format(bet)
if die1 > die2:
    print "You win ${}!</p>".format(bet*2)
if die1 < die2:
    print "You lose ${}! Try again.</p>".format(bet)

print """<img src="dice-{}.png" alt="{}" width="107" height="107" /><br />
<img src="dice-{}.png" alt="{}" width="107" height="107" />""".format(
    die1, die1, die2, die2)
```

Comment: thank you! I managed to get the images working myself, was just having trouble with doubling the bet. Now I understand where I went wrong